# How to tabulate data after using the diff function?

Tags: r, dplyr

For the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- data_frame(
  Account_Name = c("Walmart","Walmart", "Walmart","Walmart", "Walmart"),
  Close_Date = c("2013-09-20", "2014-03-31", "2014-06-02", "2014-08-29", "2014-12-31"))
```

I calculated the time difference in days of deal close dates for a client account using the diff function:

```
df2$Close_Date <- as.Date(df2$Close_Date, "%Y-%m-%d")

time_difference <- diff(df2$Close_Date)
```

The set of values I got were the following:

```
> time_difference
Time differences in days
[1] 192  63  88 124
```

What I want to know is, **how can I put the set of time_difference values into my df2 data frame** using a script. The challenge to this is that there is **one less data point** in my time_difference values than the values in df2. The end result of what I want to see it this

```
df2 <- data_frame(
  Account_Name = c("Walmart","Walmart", "Walmart","Walmart", "Walmart"),
  Close_Date = c("2013-09-20", "2014-03-31", "2014-06-02", "2014-08-29", "2014-12-31"),
  Time_Difference = c("NA", "192", "63", "88", "124"))
```

With the first item in the Time_Difference column to be filled with NA so that one less data point problem is fixed/filled.

Comment: What package are you using? `data_frame` is not a function as far as I know. Also your first code chunk is missing a `)`

Comment: @Frank thanks for catching the error! The package I'm using is Dplyr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do exactly what you want to do, and stick an `NA` out front.

```
df$Time_Difference <- c(NA, diff(df$Close_Date))
```

This is basically what you always have to do with `diff()` when you want to make it the same length as the vector in question.